# how to make a alert-output like this console-output:"console.log(`what you input is ${m}`, typeof m);"?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a comma in the `alert()` command like console command. But it does not work.

```js
alert(`what you input is ${m}`, typeof m);
console.log(`what you input is ${m}`, typeof m);
```

Comment: Documentation: [`alert`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/alert), [`console.log`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console/log).

Answer (score 3):

`alert` takes only one argument

```js
const m = 3
alert(`what you input is ${m}, ${typeof m}`);
```